# How do I access a method in the root view controller from a different class?

Tags: iphone

I apologize if this is an easy one.

I have my root view controller NB_ViewController. I have another class named ShowScreen. How can ShowScreen access a method in NB_ViewController?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a "global" property in your application delegate that retains a reference to the root view controller, e.g. `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController`
2. When you instantiate the root view controller in the app delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, set the `self.rootViewController` property equal to the newly instantiated view controller
3. Add a `#define` macro in your constants file (or in the class header where you want to use it) that lets you access the application delegate from anywhere, e.g. `#define UIAppDelegate ((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)`
4. In `ShowScreen`, call a property or method of the root view controller through the app delegate, e.g. `[[UIAppDelegate rootViewController] someRootVCProperty]` or `[[UIAppDelegate rootViewController] someRootVCMethod:foo withArgument:bar]`

Step 2 should be optional if you use Interface Builder and the corresponding root view controller `IBOutlet` is called `rootViewController`.